# Cannot connect to Azure SQL using an alpine3.8 docker image with Python

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, azure, docker, freetds

Not able to connect with Azure SQL Server through Docker container using the following code -

Based of url - [Cannot connect to Azure SQL using an alpine docker image with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904873/cannot-connect-to-azure-sql-using-an-alpine-docker-image-with-python/57483089?noredirect=1#comment101438151_57483089)

I tried different drivers but FreeTDS is not at all working.

> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (20009) (SQLDriverConnect)')

```
odbcinst.ini 
[FreeTDS]
Description=FreeTDS Driver 
Driver=/usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib/libtdsS.so
```

Comment: How are you trying to connect? With `isql` or `tsql`? If you're trying in Python, what's the code you're using for your connection string with `pyodbc`?

Answer (score 0):

Due to there are not `msodbcsql17` and `mssql-tools` packages for Apline Linux as the offical document [`Installing the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux and macOS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) list, I'm afraid you can not only use `freetds` and `unixodbc-dev` to connect Azure SQL Database v17.

As the figure below, you can see the `/etc/odbcinst.ini` content in my Ubuntu Linux. Now, to connect Azure SQL Database v17 you created in Azure Portal requires to use a specified odbc library `libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1`.

[image]

So the only solution is to switch to use `pymssql` package in Python to connect, please refer to the offical document [`Python SQL Driver - pymssql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pymssql/python-sql-driver-pymssql?view=sql-server-2017) to add the required content of `freetds-dev` and `pymssql` into your Docker file.

```
apk add freetds freetds-dev
pip install pymssql
```

Hope it helps.