# Flask pyodbc odbc connect to SQL server docker google app engine

Tags: sql-server, docker, google-app-engine, odbc, pyodbc

After trying several approaches such as  [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405777/connect-docker-python-to-sql-server-with-pyodbc/46446438#46446438) on Mac and I still get the error below when I do *gcloud app deploy*.  I also tried manually adding the freetds driver to ODBC Manager GUI but once I cick 'Ok' it doesn't show in the list of drivers. Same thing happends for the DSN for both user and system. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Step 6/14 : ADD odbcinst.ini /etc/odbcinst.ini
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder438222044/odbcinst.ini: no such file or directory
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1

Comment: Could you please share your configuration files, to clarify, such as Dockerfile, yaml file and requirements.txt file? Additionally, is there any further documentation you may have followed? If so could you please provide the link? On the SO post you mentioned, reading [an additional answer](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://stackoverflow.com/a/48975483/11928130&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1585742502320000&usg=AFQjCNHGNDfA4FKSWVOYnaZvLyZHsb5LnQ)  make sure that the paths of the library should reflect the actual paths according to your architecture.

Comment: I solved it after the fact by adding some extra stuff to the dockerfile. Thank you so much for offering your help.

Comment: I'm glad you figured the solution. Could you please post this as an answer to your post, in order to give visibility for future reference in the community?