# Azure Function App in Docker Desktop does not have access to local sql server database on host

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, docker, azure-functions

I have my mssql server on my local windows desktop, which hold the development database for my application. I have a Azure function app that is written in python which has a couple endpoints that query the database.

If I run this function app in VSCode is connects to the database file. It uses the following env variables:

```
    "DB_HOST": "HOME\\SQLEXPRESS",
    "DB_NAME": "devdb.local",
    "DB_USERNAME": "user",
    "DB_PASS": "...",
```

I am trying to run my function app in docker and docker desktop in Linux containers so I can run multiple function app at the same time.

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster

# Set a non-root user and create the working directory.
WORKDIR /app

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    wget \
    gnupg \
    apt-transport-https \
    lsb-release \
    # Add Microsoft package signing key and repository
    && wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc -O- | apt-key add - \
    && wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update \
    # Install ODBC Driver for SQL Server
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 \
    # Other dependencies
    && apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev \
    && apt-get install -y libicu-dev \
    && apt-get install -y azure-functions-core-tools-4 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /packages-microsoft-prod.deb

# Copy only the requirements file and install Python dependencies.
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application code.
COPY . .

# Expose the port on which the app will run.
EXPOSE 7071

# Start the function app.
CMD ["func", "start", "--python"]
```

Docker Compose File:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    image: func-app:latest
    ports:
      - "8001:7071"
    environment:
      - AzureWebJobsStorage=UseDevelopmentStorage=true
      - AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags=EnableWorkerIndexing
      - FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME=python
      - ENVIRONMENT=dev
      - DB_HOST=HOME\\SQLEXPRESS
      - DB_NAME=devdb.local
      - DB_USERNAME=user
      - DB_PASS=...
      - AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONNECTIONSTRING=...
      - AZURE_CONTAINER=media
      - CARD_MARKET_APP_SECRET=...
      - CARD_MARKET_APP_TOKEN=...
      - DEV_SHOP=...
      - SETS_PROCESSED=100
    command: ["func", "start", "--python"]
```

When I run this in docker desktop that app runs as expected but I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": "Database connection failed: Failed to connect to database: ('01000', \"[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.10.so.5.1' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)\")"
}
```

in my requirements.txt I have the packages for database connection:

- mysql-connector-python==8.2.0
- pyodbc==5.0.1

I cant seem to figure out why my function app in a docker contain does have access to my database on the host.

Comment: @Ross- Make sure you have installed ODBC Driver in the docker container- Dockerfile:


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    unixodbc \
    unixodbc-dev \
    libgssapi-krb5-2 \
    odbcinst \
    libodbc1 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

Comment: After installing the ODBC driver, you can configure it by adding the following lines to your Dockerfile:


COPY odbcinst.ini /etc/
COPY odbc.ini /etc/

Comment: You will also need to create the odbcinst.ini and odbc.ini files in the same directory as your Dockerfile. These files should contain the configuration information for the ODBC driver. Here is an example odbcinst.ini file:


[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.8.so.1.1
UsageCount=1

And here is an example odbc.ini file:


[mydsn]
Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Server=HOME\\SQLEXPRESS
Database=devdb.local

Comment: Then update volume in your dockercompose file like this :- version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    image: func-app:latest
    ports:
      - "8001:7071"
    environment:
      - AzureWebJobsStorage=UseDevelopmentStorage=true
      - AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags=EnableWorkerIndexing
      - FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME=python
      - ENVIRONMENT=dev
      - AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONNECTIONSTRING=...
      - AZURE_CONTAINER=media
      - CARD_MARKET_APP_SECRET=...
      - CARD_MARKET_APP_TOKEN=...
      - DEV_SHOP=...
      - SETS_PROCESSED=100

Comment: volumes:
      - ./odbcinst.ini:/etc/odbcinst.ini
      - ./odbc.ini:/etc/odbc.ini
    command: ["func", "start", "--python"]

Comment: Hello, @SiddheshDesai thank you for you response. Could you please put this in answer as it is quite hard to following in the comments without any formatting.

Comment: Aside... `apt-key add` has been deprecated for a while now (since at least Debian 9). You might wish to review the proper way to get the signing keys, [Microsoft ODBC 17](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=alpine18-install%2Cdebian17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline).

Comment: Aside... Microsoft has a habit of randomly breaking `unixodbc-dev` in their own package repo, I'd suggest installing it directly from the Debian repo before adding references to `packages.microsoft.com`. You might also want include `ca-certificates` in your first `apt-get install` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comments as an answer for the benefit of the community:-

You need to install ODBC Driver in your Docker container too for the driver to connect to SQL:-

***You can install the ODBC driver by using this command:-***

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    unixodbc \
    unixodbc-dev \
    libgssapi-krb5-2 \
    odbcinst \
    libodbc1 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Once the ODBC driver is installed, use the below lines into your Dockerfile to set up its configuration:

```
COPY odbcinst.ini /etc/
COPY odbc.ini /etc/
```

Additionally, it's necessary to generate the `odbcinst.ini` and `odbc.ini` files within the same location as your Dockerfile. These files must hold the setup details for the ODBC driver.

**odbcinst.ini file:-**

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.8.so.1.1 UsageCount=1 And here is an example odbc.ini file: [mydsn] Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server Server=HOME\\SQLEXPRESS Database=devdb.local
```

**odbc.ini:-**

```
[mydsn] 
Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL 
Server Server=HOME\\SQLEXPRESS 
Database=devdb.local
```

***Docker compose File:-***

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    image: func-app:latest
    ports:
      - "8001:7071"
    environment:
      - AzureWebJobsStorage=UseDevelopmentStorage=true
      - AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags=EnableWorkerIndexing
      - FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME=python
      - ENVIRONMENT=dev
      - AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONNECTIONSTRING=...
      - AZURE_CONTAINER=media
      - CARD_MARKET_APP_SECRET=...
      - CARD_MARKET_APP_TOKEN=...
      - DEV_SHOP=...
      - SETS_PROCESSED=100
    volumes:
      - ./odbcinst.ini:/etc/odbcinst.ini
      - ./odbc.ini:/etc/odbc.ini
    command: ["func", "start", "--python"]
```

Complete **`DockerFile`**:-

```
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    wget \
    gnupg \
    apt-transport-https \
    lsb-release \
    # Add Microsoft package signing key and repository
    && wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc -O- | apt-key add - \
    && wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update \
    # Install ODBC Driver for SQL Server
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 \
    # Other dependencies
    && apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev \
    && apt-get install -y libicu-dev \
    && apt-get install -y azure-functions-core-tools-4 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /packages-microsoft-prod.deb

# Set a non-root user and create the working directory.
WORKDIR /app

# Copy only the requirements file and install Python dependencies.
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application code.
COPY . .

# Expose the port on which the app will run.
EXPOSE 7071

# Set environment variables.
ENV DB_HOST=HOME\\SQLEXPRESS \
    DB_NAME=devdb.local \
    DB_USERNAME=user \
    DB_PASS=...

# Copy the ODBC configuration files.
COPY odbcinst.ini /etc/
COPY odbc.ini /etc/

# Start the function app.
CMD ["func", "start", "--python"]
```

**Reference:-**

[dockerfile - Connect docker python to SQL server with pyodbc - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405777/connect-docker-python-to-sql-server-with-pyodbc)

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting: `"Database connection failed: Failed to connect to database: ('01000', \"[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)\")"` I have added the `idbcinst.ini` and `odbc.ini` files. with the correct location to the  driver in the opt/microsoft/... location.

Comment: Try to run this:- RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    curl \
    sudo \
    apt-transport-https \
    gnupg \
    unixodbc-dev \
    libgssapi-krb5-2 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Download and add Microsoft GPG key
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc

# Choose the appropriate package for the OS version (Debian 11 in this case)
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

Comment: # Update package list and install Microsoft ODBC Driver 17
RUN apt-get update && \
    ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends msodbcsql17 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

Comment: Looks like you seem to have resolved the ODBC issue here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77795735/failed-to-connect-to-database-hyt00-hyt00-microsoftodbc-driver-17-for