# Failed to connect to database: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, docker, odbc

I have an Azure Function app, which has a couple endpoints, written in Python and it is running in a docker container in Docker Desktop. The Function App seems to run correctly but when I try to call the endpoint I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": "Database connection failed: Failed to connect to database: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')"
}
```

My SQL Server is installed on my local windows desktop. The Function App works as expected and connects to the database if I run the function application within VSCode using Azurite. I am not sure its struggling with the connection to the database.

database_helper.py

```
...
def load_environment_variables():
    # Loads required environment variables for database connection.
    # Raises an error if any required variable is missing.
    required_vars = ['DB_HOST', 'DB_NAME', 'DB_USERNAME', 'DB_PASS']
    env_vars = {}
    for var in required_vars:
        value = os.getenv(var)
        if not value:
            raise EnvironmentError(f"Missing required environment variable: {var}")
        env_vars[var] = value
    return env_vars

def create_connection_string(env_vars):
    # Constructs a connection string for the database using environment variables.
    return (
        f"Driver={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}};"
        f"Server={env_vars['DB_HOST']};"
        f"Database={env_vars['DB_NAME']};"
        f"UID={env_vars['DB_USERNAME']};"
        f"PWD={env_vars['DB_PASS']};" #NOSONAR
    )

def get_connection():
    # Establishes a database connection using the connection string.
    # Handles pyodbc connection errors and logs them.
    env_vars = load_environment_variables()
    connection_string = create_connection_string(env_vars)

    try:
        return pyodbc.connect(connection_string, autocommit=False)
    except pyodbc.Error as e:
        logger.error(f"Error connecting to database: {e}")
        raise DatabaseConnectionError(f"Failed to connect to database: {e}") from e

class DatabaseManager:
    # Manages database operations within a context manager.
    def __init__(self):
        # Initializes a database connection and cursor.
        self.connection = get_connection()
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
...
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Use the Azure Functions Python image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.10-core-tools

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    unixodbc-dev \
    gnupg \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /packages-microsoft-prod.deb

# Install Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server (Debian 11)
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /packages-microsoft-prod.deb

# Copy only the requirements file and install Python dependencies.
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application code.
COPY . .

# Expose the port on which the app will run.
EXPOSE 7071

# Copy the ODBC configuration files.
COPY odbcinst.ini /etc/
COPY odbc.ini /etc/

# Start the function app.
CMD ["func", "start", "--python"]
```

odbcinst.ini & odbc.ini

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server 
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.10.so.5.1 
UsageCount=1


[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Server=host.docker.internal\\SQLEXPRESS
Database=dev.local
```

Docker Compose:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    image: func-app:latest
    ports:
      - "8001:7071"
    environment:
      - AzureWebJobsStorage=...
      - AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags=EnableWorkerIndexing
      - FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME=python
      - ENVIRONMENT=dev
      - DB_HOST=host.docker.internal\\SQLEXPRESS
      - DB_NAME=dev.local
      - DB_USERNAME=user
      - DB_PASS=admin
      - AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONNECTIONSTRING=...
      - AZURE_CONTAINER=media
      - DEV_SHOP=...
      - SETS_PROCESSED=100
    command: ["func", "start", "--python"]
```

Comment: If you open the SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager tool and check the Server Protocols for the SQLEXPRESS instance... is the TCP/IP protocol enabled? Does the TCP/IP protocol have any ports enabled on any address other than `127.0.0.1`? If you make any changes in here you'll need to restart both the SQLEXPRESS instance as well as the SQL Browser service (which is responsible for resolving instance names to the TCP port/s that they're listening on).

Comment: @Ross > Try to inspect the Docker networking by using this command - docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <container_name_or_id> Check the IP of the Docker, See if it is allowed in your SQL server. Run your docker image in the same network host as your Function app, Run this command - docker run --network host <image_name>

Comment: Also, Try to map the port to host by running this command - docker run -p 8080:7071 <image_name>

Comment: TCP/IP is enabled. If I look at the IP Addresses in properties, all of them are active, none of them are enabled, and none of them have TCP Ports set. The port is set correctly on the container as I can go to `localhost:8001` and it brings up the Azure Function App landing screening and the error I am getting is a Json response from the endpoint.

Comment: Try to add connection string like this - connectionString = "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=azure-sql-server.database.windows.net;Database=azuresqldb;Uid=siliconuser;Pwd=<password>;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;LongAsMax=1; with timeout

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue I had to run the following in my SQL Server database:

```sql
USE master
GO
xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on', N'any', NULL, NULL, N'asc' 
GO
```

This gave me the port that is it running on. Then in my Docker Compose file I had to update the following environment variable:

```
    ...
    environment:
        - DB_HOST=host.docker.internal,<port>
    ...
```

After this, my function app endpoints were able to connect to the database and return data.